# How do I get rid of phantom bookmarks in Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm running Chrome 5.0.375.38 on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and although I'm positive that when I installed it I told it NOT to import my Firefox bookmarks, it nevertheless still accessed my OLD Firefox bookmarks (including some that I deleted) when I used the location bar. HOWEVER, when I opened the bookmarks manager, it said that I have no bookmarks whatsoever.

Seeking to solve this problem, I installed XMarks on both FF and Chrome, and forced Chrome to download the server bookmarks. Now Chrome lists all my current FF bookmarks, but STILL sees the old, phantom bookmarks from when I first installed Chrome in the location bar, even though when I search for these same bookmarks in the bookmarks manager they don't show up.

Aargh! Any ideas? Even if there's some way to force-kill-wipeout-clean-erase ALL my Chrome bookmarks that's fine as long as it kills the phantom ones b/c I can still overwrite with XMarks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a Bookmarks file in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks

So try deleting that - if not I would delete all of ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome

Comment: I think the issue is that the bookmarks somehow got imported into my list of keyword search engines so I manually deleted them from that list, but I'll keep deleting that directory in mind if this seeming solution doesn't persist. Thanks!